# Reality of Hermitian Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, complex-numbers

I know that Hermitian Operators have all their eigenvalues real. But are the operators themselves real too? So if A is an Hermitian Operator, should it be real, and thus, A = A* be true?

Comment: Hint: Think of the Pauli matrix $\sigma_y$.

Comment: They are self-adjoint, not real... as explained in any QM text.

Comment: Not necessarily! If you represent any operator in terms of matrix, than only condition needed to be satisfied is that upper triangular elements of that matrix should be complex conjugate of corresponding lower triangular elements and diagonal elements should be real. Which makes $A=A^{\dagger}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Real" for an operator does not mean anything. At most you can wonder if the *matrix* of the operator is real. It depends on the used basis. If the basis is made of eigenvectors and the operator is Hermitian then the matrix is real, since it is diagonal with the (real) eigenvalues on the principal diagonal. Otherwise it may be complex even the operator is Hermitian (Pauli matrices).